# Access this object's name

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm attempting to "loop" through an object and grab the name if a certain test passes.

For instance

```
var x = {
 'first':[
        'ab',
        'abc',
 ],
 'second':[
        'sia',
        'sss'
 ],
 'third':[
        'jp',
        'jh'
 ]
};
```

As you can see, I have an object containing arrays.

Let's say that I am given the value "sss" .... I am trying to figure out how to get Javascript to output "second" when given the appropriate value.

The same goes for the following scenarios

```
third for jp
third for jh
first for abc
```

and so on.

Comment: You need a recursive function over the object and returns a depth counter when prop/value is reached

Comment: That's fairly simple to do, have you tried anything that *didn't work*?

Comment: Quick googling gives me at least 20 viable hits that answer your question. Although this forum is for providing answers - you need to search for the answers yourself first. 
Here's a little push - just look at the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility (where x is your object, and y is your desired array value):

```
function foo(y) {
  for (key in x) {
    if (x[key].indexOf(y) > -1) {
      return key;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will find the first key that has the value you are searching for in its array

```
function myFunction(searchValue, myObject){
    for(var i in myObject){
        if(myObject.hasOwnProperty(i) && myObject[i].indexOf(searchValue) != -1){
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You know what.  No sooner I click Submit Question, did I realized how to do it.

```
var x = {
 'first':[
        'ab','abc',
 ],
 'second':[
        'sia','sss'
 ],
 'third':[
        'jp','jh',
 ]
};

for(var arr in x) {
   var theArr = x[arr];
   if(theArr.indexOf("sss") !== -1) console.log(arr) // returns "second"
}
```

Comment: Heh!  I love that of the myriad ways this could be solved we both came up with the exact same method within 10 seconds of each other

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to exclude properties in the prototype chain use the hasOwnProperty function:

```
  for (var property in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      console.log('property: ' + property + ' value: ' + obj[property]);
    }
  }
```

The in operator will traverse the prototype chain and return all properties in the object.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = {
 'first':[
        'ab',
        'abc',
 ],
 'second':[
        'sia',
        'sss'
 ],
 'third':[
        'jp',
        'jh'
 ]
};

var result = Object.keys(x).filter(function(key) {
  return x[key].indexOf('sss') > -1;
});
```

Afterwards, `result` will be an array containing all keys that contain the value `sss`, so it could be 0, 1 or more, if duplicates exist.